# Is my question about the difference between spell ranges "Self" vs. "Self (XYZ)" really a duplicate of this question about "Self"-range spell targets?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, duplicates

My most recent question, [What is the difference between a spell with a range of "Self" and a spell with a range of "Self (XYZ)"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177381/52137), has been marked as a duplicate twice (it was closed as a dupe, then reopened, then reclosed again) of the question [Do spells with a range of "Self" target the caster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71791/do-spells-with-a-range-of-self-target-the-caster). It is not, in my opinion, but would like to get some commentary on it.

The linked question is asking about whether or not spells with a range of "Self" target the caster. My question is both broader in scope, by asking about both "Self" and "Self (XYZ)", as well as not particularly caring about whether or not the caster is the actual target.

The focus of my question really is "*What is the difference between 'Self' and 'Self (XYZ)'?*"
This is not the same thing as "*Does a spell with a range of 'Self' target the caster?*". Regardless of whether or not the caster is targeted by one or other definitions, I want to know the difference between these.

Answer (score 18):

## Not a duplicate

There must be a difference between self and self(range). This question is asking that difference.

If there is no difference, then that's an answer, but it's not the same as "Do spells with range of self target the caster"

That isn't what this  question is asking at all. It may end up containing a similar answer, but that's not a duplicate criteria.